# how to get .tex file from .texi?

Tags: pdftex, texi2dvi, texinfo

need to receive source `tex` file of [MPFR documentation](https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.pdf), which is built from [mpfr.texi](https://gitlab.inria.fr/mpfr/mpfr/-/blob/master/doc/mpfr.texi) using [Texinfo](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/). ideally to get `tex` file:

- without dependencies like Texinfo,
- without Texinfo macroces, not used in the source `texi` file,
- which can be recognized by any editor, able to build LaTeX files.

<s>found, that `pdfTeX` from MiKTeX package directly produce `pdf` file from `texi`. which mean it should preprocess `texi` file, putting [texinfo.tex](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/texinfo.git/) macroses into it, and complile `pdf` from the *result*. that *result* expected to be the required `tex` file.</s>

unfortunately `pdfTeX -output-format=FORMAT` option supports only FORMAT `dvi` or `pdf`. is there any way to make `pdfTeX` to save preprocessed `texi` to file instead of compiling it? like using debug version, undocumented option or something.

as @DavidCarlisle clarified in discussion below, there is no preprocess stage prior compiling `pdf` files. so no way to get is from LaTeX software.
just as no such functionality in `texi2any` from Texinfo package.

is there any solution available but wrighting own `texi` parcer from stratch?

Alex Shevchenko

Comment: What gives you the impression that there's a plain TeX or LaTeX `.tex` file involved here? As far as I can see, you simply build a PDF using the appropriate macros and the `.texi` source file.

Comment: a texi file _is_ tex there is no conversion involved.

Comment: the escape char in texinfo happens to be `@` rather than `\ ` but tex just uses that as specified, it never converts the command marked up as `@title`  to `\title` it just executes `@title` directly.

Comment: @JosephWright, the impression that `pdfTeX` can be considered as a compiler, and compilers usually preprocess source files prior building em

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, it's not that kind of `tex`, which can be used and compiled with TeX editor.
we can discuss the accuracy of the definitions, but this will not change purpose of this thread: get completed `tex` file, without 3rdpatry dependencies like Texinfo. is there any way except manual copy-paste?
PS: misclicks happens

Comment: tex processes the file a character at a time typesetting as it goes, it never preprocesses the file to the more common `\ ` and `{}` syntax. That syntax is not built in to tex, the choice of `\ ` or `@` as escape char is purely a matter of local settings. If the editor does not understand the texinfo sysntax that is a problem with the editor only accepting a subset of tex syntax. emacs has support for texinfo for example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for clarification with processing tex files, updated topic description. but I can't confirm a *problem with the editor*. Texinfo is not a part of LaTeX project, so it's unfair to expect from LaTeX editors to support `texi` format out of the box

Comment: Compared to latex there are some syntactic differences eg using `@` instead of `\ ` they are fairly trivial to address: I show a latex document using `@` in my answer you could use `\ ` with texinfo. But what do you want to do with  the typesetting macros in texinfo.tex defining page and headings and cross references etc? you need _some_ macros?  If you simply want to avoid a file then you can replace `\input texinfo` by the contents of texinfo.tex. That would address the first two points but why do this? why is relying on texinfo.tex any different to relying on article.sty ?

Comment: you are really confused: \*TeX\* is a (family of) typesetter(s), and it/they can typeset different document formats loading the appropriate macros. For \*LaTeX files you need the \*LaTeX format and a lot of other stuff, and for Texinfo you only need the Plain format and the texinfo.tex macro file, perhaps with other couple of things. So, in a way, a Texinfo file is a TeX file already, although in a document format very much unlike LaTeX or Plain.

Comment: there are a couple of ways to transform `texi` files into `latex`, but usually it's not worth it.

Comment: @jarnosz, I'm not confused, but misunderstood. have to repeat, I'm not interested to discuss the accuracy of definitions, whether `texi` format can be considered as `tex` or not. of course Texinfo files are TeX, they just have `.texi` extension instead of `.tex` for some reason, and lot of TeX editors have no fainest idea about that kind of "TeX"...

Comment: ...the purpose of this topic was to find a solution to get `.tex` file from `.texi`. a file, that not just can be built with `pdfTeX` (which can be solved by copy-paste of `texinfo.tex` content), but also understandable for TeX editors like TeXworks. unfortunately I didn't succeeded with that even trying tips from the Community. so just stopped escalate this issue

Comment: If all you want to do is to edit the Texinfo file with a LaTeX editor, simply replace all `@`s with `\ ` and declare `@catcode\`@\=0` (exactly the opposite to what David states in his answer), and hope for the best. It's a horrible kludge, but easier than reading your mind.

Comment: tried that multiple times but it just didn't work for me. and trying to make it work is not worth the time of the Community or anyone else

Comment: From what you say, I collect that you believe `Texinfo` is a "high level language", which needs some preprocessing to convert it to `TeX` syntax at a lower level, just as some C sources are preprocessed before feeding the compiler, but that's a mistake: a Texinfo.texi file compiles directly into pdf/dvi from source with pdf/TeX by loading its own set of macros; `Texinfo` or `LaTeX` are macro packages for `TeX` just as `ms` or `man` are macro packages for `groff`. So, you must learn LaTeX or Texinfo syntax separately, just the same as you need to learn `man` or `ms` syntax separately.

Comment: @AlexShevchenko - Have you tried [texi2latex](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/texi2latex)?

Answer (score 4):

The choice of special syntax characters is not built in to TeX, latex and plain TeX use `\`  as the escapechar to prefix command names, but this not the only possibility, the current value of `\escapechar` specifies which character is used.

This latex file uses `@` rather than `\`  so looks more like texinfo than latex

```
\catcode`\@=0

@documentclass{article}

@begin{document}

@section{Intro}

@textbf{this} that

@end{document}
```

It produces

[image]

when processed with latex.

At no point does tex pre-process this into `\`-syntax file, it simply is not necessary, the syntax `@textbf` is as valid to get bold as `\textbf` they both refer to the tex command `textbf` using the currently specified escape char.

Similarly the fact that the  texinfo file inputs `texinfo.tex` is no different to this latex file inputting `article.cls` tex never expands the whole document replacing latex commands such as `@section` (`\section`) by tex primitives, rather each command is executed as it is encountered and expanded and executed to start generating the PDF output. In larger documents the first pages of the PDF may be written before later parts of the document have even been read from the filesystem.

So the texinfo file is TeX just as a latex file is tex, or `xii.tex` that you can find on ctan.